# Kubuntu 20.04 - Hotspot from Android keep disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, internet

I searched on the web and on this site, but I couldn't figure out a solution.

I don't have WiFi at home, I use my android phone as a hotspot.

When I connect to the hotspot from the laptop (Acer Swift 1 SF114-32) on which I had installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS every 20 mins or so, even if the icon on the bottom bar indicates that the hotspot is connected, internet stops working.

I have to turn off the WiFi and turn on it again.

While it could mbe manageable for simple tasks it makes it impossible to do anything that requires the connection to be on for a long period of time (like updates, or streaming).

I searched the web but I couldn't find a solution.

I thought the fault was my phone, but since I also have an XBOX one, and I connect it to the internet using the same hotspot, I don't have any problem at all.

I can download games and updates that take hours and the connection is stable.

What can be the issue?

Where can I look to try to solve this very annoying problem?

here's the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 03)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 605 (rev 03)
00:0c.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 31dc (rev 03)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 03)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 31e3 (rev 03)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f3)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 31a8 (rev 03)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b4 (rev 03)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31e8 (rev 03)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 03)
```

EDIT:

I had a look at the journalctl log, but unfortunately I couldn't find any information about my problem. Yesterday, for example, at 10.17 AM internet stopped working again, and here is the corresponding line in the log:

```
set 30 10:17:10 zotnam NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1632989830.7724] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1364 uid=1000 result="success"
```

As you can see I can't find anything useful. I'm really struggling to find what the problem could be.

Thanks in advance to all that will help me.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the logs but couldn't find anything wrong. The internet stopped working at 10.17 and here's the line: `set 30 10:17:10 zotnam NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1632989830.7724] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1364 uid=1000 result="success"`  Can't figure out what the problem could be

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]